# Include example using data in documentation of that data (when developing R package)

Tags: r, package, rstudio, roxygen

In documentation of data within an R package (using Roxygen via Rstudio), is it possible to include an example that uses that data?

E.g. TestPackage.R in the R directory

```
#' My New Colour
#' 
#' Enables use of my new colour \emph{aNewColour} in plots.
#' @name aNewColour
#' @docType data
#' @format A colour defined by rgb(red=232,green=81,blue=0,maxColorValue=255)
#' @usage data(allNewColours)
#' @examples
#' curve(dnorm,from=-4,to=4,col=aNewColour,lwd=2)
NULL
```

In the same R directory, I have a file: *allNewColours.rda*, which consists only of the variable *aNewColour* with value *#E85100*.

When I press *Check* on the *Build* menu of R studio (equivalent to the command *R CMD Check* I believe), I get the following error message:

> > #### ** Examples
> >
> > curve(dnorm,from=-4,to=4,col=aNewColour,lwd=2) Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : object 'aNewColour' not found Calls: curve -> plot ->
> >     plot.default -> plot.xy Execution halted Error: Command failed (1)
> >     Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

Is it possible to use the data "aNewColour" in the example of the documentation of "aNewColour" ?

**Edit**: Okay I found my problem - If I move the *.rda* file to a data folder (at the same level as the *R* folder, all works)... Had been struggling with this for ages only to determine the solution within seconds of posting this question ...

Comment: See Edit for solution to problem.  This now works.  I needed to have my .rda file in a data directory at the same level as the R directory

Comment: It should also be noted that this example requires LazyData: yes in the DESCRIPTION file, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Answer as an official answer and mark correct

Comment: BTW, with roxygen2, you can now document `"aNewColour"` and it will fill in the name etc. with the correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the .rda file to a data folder - and enter *LazyData: yes* in the DESCRIPTION file